# How to style an alert with two call to actions

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create an alert using html and css to look like this example below

[image: Example]

I've been able to create this using inline CSS and it is not the desired look I was hoping for.

What is the best away to adjust my current code in order to achieve the look of the example? At the moment I using two separate divs and adjusting the margins.

[image]

```html
<div class="row" id="alert_box">
  <div class="col m2">
    <div class="card red darken-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 40px">What information do you want to see? We'd love to hear from you</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col m1" style="
    margin-left: -23px">
    <div class="card red darken-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <p>button 1</p>
        </div>
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <p>button 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p style="margin-bottom: 40px">` Will push everything up and out, does it need to be there?

Comment: I'm currently using the margin-bottom to match the height of the second div. Not the most efficient way of doing so, it does not need to be there.

Comment: You should take a look at flexbox it's pretty easy with that.

Comment: To get you started https://jsfiddle.net/ukbd4z38/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using bootstrap, then flex or grid can help you here :

flex possible example,  both columns will be stretching to match the highest:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.alert,
.alert button {
  background: rgb(200, 35, 51);
  color: beige
}

.col,
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.m-auto {
  margin: auto;
}

.m1 {
  margin: 1em;
}

div,
button {
  border: solid 1px #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="row alert m1">
  <div class="colt flex-3 flex-column ">
    <p class="m-auto">some text standing here</p>
    <p class="m-auto">some text standing here</p>
    <p class="m-auto">some text standing here</p>
    <p class="m-auto">some text standing here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col flex-column">
    <button class="flex-1">button 1</button>
    <button class="flex-1">button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row alert m1">
  <div class="colt flex-3 flex-column ">
    <p class="m-auto">some text standing here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col flex-column">
    <button class="flex-1">button 1</button>
    <button class="flex-1">button 2</button>
    <button class="flex-1">button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row bg-secondary text-light" id="alert_box" style="max-width:516px;">
  <div class="col-9" style="padding: 13px 6px 11px 33px;border-right: 1px solid #fff;">
    What information do you want to see? We'd love to hear from you
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">
        <button class="btn pull-right text-light">Button 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
         <button class="btn pull-right text-light">Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check this live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vqhyea85/)

Comment: Can you set it as answer for your question?